# Is there a way to find the number of rows of any table using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am setting up various HTML tables on my web page and want to find a way of knowing the number of rows each of them contain in jQuery without using classes or id in the tables. Is this possible?

I have already tried linking up an HTML button with a click event handler to get the closest table and compute its length, but I seem to be doing something wrong here.

I would like to find the length of any table to be able to change the action of the button, depending on the number of rows left in the table.

The actual output of rowCount is `1`, whenever I try it on any size table.

```js
$(document).on("click", "button.x-cross", function() {
  var rowCount = $(this).closest("table >tr").length;

  // Conditions using the rowCount variable

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>First row</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="x-cross">X</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in your code is that the `table` is the closest parent element to the button, not `table > tr`, hence that selector doesn't find anything. If you separate the selector in to `closest()` and then `find()`, it works:

```js
$(document).on("click", "button.x-cross", function() {
  var rowCount = $(this).closest("table").find('tr').length;
  console.log(rowCount);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>First row</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="x-cross">X</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>First row</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Second row</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Third row</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="x-cross">X</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer, it solved my problem. But I can't wrap my head around the table being the closest parent to the button as you said.

Comment: The selector you provide to `closest()` is used to match the parent element in a loop. In other words it check if the `table > tr` selector matches the parent `tr`, which it doesn't. Similarly, it doesn't match the `table` either, hence nothing is found. You need to separate the logic for finding the closest parent `table`, then finding all the `tr`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eq` to select the table of your choice

```js
console.log('First :' + $('table').eq(0).find('tr').length)
console.log('Second :' + $('table').eq(1).find('tr').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>First row</span>
    </td>
    <td>
     
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Second row</span>
    </td>
    <td>
     
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Third row</span>
    </td>
    <td>
     
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```